# How to open files from Terminal

Tags: python, terminal

How can you open a file from the terminal. For example from terminal how can I open a .txt or .py file?

Comment: In what way do you want to open it? Do you want to edit the file, just view it, run it, or something else?

Comment: I would like to open it so I can edit it.

Comment: You want to edit it using what application?

Comment: lets say I want to open a python file and edit it in Thonny. how would I do this from the terminal?

Comment: @linuxuser1 Thonny is a GUI program; running it from the terminal doesn't make a lot of sense unless you already have a GUI set up. Are you already running one (e.g. PIXEL)?

Comment: @linuxuser1 Try `thonny file.py`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To **view** the text file you could use `less` or `cat`.

Example: `cat /path/file.txt`. Of course this works only if the file is readable for your user account. For details please read the manpage: `man cat`.

To **edit** a file you can choose between many editors. I recommend to start with `nano`. A good read: [Raspberry Pi Documentation - Text editors](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/text-editors.md).

To learn more command line basics I recommend the eBook [The MagPi Essentials - Conquer The Command Line](https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/issues/essentials-bash-vol1/) (you can download it for free).

Answer (score 1):

**Simple Answer**

To view a *python* / *text file* you can use [**cat**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cat.1.html) command.

`cat /home/pi/documents/yourfile.txt`

To edit a *python* / *text file* you can use [**vim**](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/help.html) or [**nano**](https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.0/nano.html) commands.

vim - `vim ~/yourfile.txt`
nano - `nano ~/yourfile.py`

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

```
nano file.txt
```

Or

```
nano /home/user/documents/file.txt
```

Ctrl+x to close.